# Invalid pointer - why?

Tags: c++, pointers

Not very experienced with C++, I've got the following:

```
void read_image(vector<unsigned char>* buffer) {
    buffer = new vector<unsigned char>(2048);
}   

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    vector< unsigned char > *buffer;

    read_image(buffer);

    delete buffer; // gives invalid pointer at run-time

    return 0;
}
```

This is only the relevant part of the code, basically I want to initialize the pointer `buffer` in `read_image()`. At run-time I'm getting this when trying to free up the heap:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./main: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff0648556c ***
```

What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not sending `buffer` by reference (or as a pointer to `vector<unsigned char>*) when calling`read_image`, therefor the function is unable to propagate the update to outside of the function (ie. the caller).

---

This modification of your function will result in what you wish:

```
void read_image(vector<unsigned char>*& buffer) {
    buffer = new vector<unsigned char>(2048);
}
```

We are now passing a reference as a parameter to `read_image`, and the original variable will be updated with the value returned from `new vector<...> (...)`.

---

If you are a *pointer fanatic* this is also valid:

```
void read_image (vector<unsigned char>** buffer) {
    *buffer = new vector<unsigned char>(2048);
}  

...

read_image (&buffer);
```

In the above we are giving read_image the address of the pointer itself, and inside we can dereference this pointer to pointer to set the value pointed to by the original pointer.

Excuse the wording, I'm quite tired to be honest.

---

FAQ regarding the use of references.

- [**parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/** - [8] References](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references)

Comment: The real question, however, is why he is allocating a `vector` dynamically to begin with.  There are very, very few cases where it makes sense to dynamically allocate a `vector`.

Comment: @rdoubleui If you want to modify a pointer in the calling function, you need to pass a reference to that pointer.  Pointers are no different than any other data type in that regard.

Comment: @rdoubleui Yes, you are passing the value of the pointer (which will be turned into a local copy inside your function), not the pointer itself in your original code.

Comment: Ok, @James I wanted to allocate it dynamically because I read a picture of unknown dimensions.

Comment: @rdoubleui std::vector<T> will handle that for you though, it's a dynamic container (with that said; it can change size during runtime if necessary).

Answer (score 2):

```
void read_image(vector<unsigned char>* & buffer) { // passed by reference
    buffer = new vector<unsigned char>(2048);
}   

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    vector< unsigned char > *buffer;

    read_image(buffer);

    delete buffer; // gives invalid pointer at run-time

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to create buffer which can hold more than one image otherwise I dont know why you need a vector here.

if my guess about your requirement is correct you should do something like this -

```
void read_image(vector<unsigned char*>& buffer,int size) { 
    char* p = new char[size];
    buffer.push_back(p);
}
void process_image_buffer(char* image_buffer) {
    // Do something with image_buffer
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    vector<unsigned char*> buffer;
    for all images
       // calculate the unknown size at runtime here e.g.by taking input from user
       read_image(buffer,size);

    // Do Image Processing
    // process each image buffer in a for loop
    for all images (i < buffer.size())
       process_image_buffer(buffer[i]);

    // Free all at end
    for all images (i < buffer.size()) 
       delete[] buffer[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, there's only one image. How would you handle image processing without a vector having a single image?

Comment: @rdoubleui : Added a process_image_buffer function above to answer your query.

Comment: Okay, you're suggesting a `char` Array instead of a `vector`. Is there any benefit of using it instead of passing a `vector` reference?